# How do I keep the bricks in my texture the same size over an object with increasing size?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I have modeled the column and unwrapped it like so:

[image: Model]

The question I have is regarding the top curved portion that splays out. I was simply thinking of doing this:

[image: UV Map]

Then it renders out like this:

[image: Rendered Scene]

Are there any other ways to deal with applying flat textures to curved trapezoidal surfaces such as this?

Comment: First, the images used as textures seem to have different scale. Second, UV map seems to be stretched in the top. Lastly, if you want to use maximum of the texture space probably it would be better to use Smart UV Project unwrap - but it will be much more complex to edit the texture manually afterwards (as the unwrap might be a bit hard to understand).

Comment: You can also use the UV Project modifier : it will "guaranty" to keep the texture proportional everywhere.